# What's the point of these regex'es?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to solve a regex puzzle, and portions of the regexes keep consisting of pieces like this:

`([^Xa-ehY]|[^f-zW])`

or

`([^2]|[^D-Za]|[D-Ze-f])`

These confuse me.

Take the first one, for example: `[^Xa-ehY]|[^f-zW])`. Doesn't this mean "not Xa-ehY OR not f-zW"? And doesn't that equate to "any character"? Take `e` for example. It wouldn't match the first one, but it would match the second. `W` would not match the second, but it would match the first.

Same with `([^2]|[^D-Za]|[D-Ze-f])`. This means "not 2 OR not D-Ze-f OR D-Ze-f", right? Which again amounts to "any character."

Am I missing something? Is this just a convoluted substitution for a single `.` regex?

Comment: Are these from some regex book's exercises? They indeed look like convoluted substitutions for . :)

Comment: No -- amazing site called Hackquest. It's a javascript puzzle where you have to figure out what password will get through a sequence of 15 consecutive Regexes. It's very fun-- highly recommended for the passionate regexer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are some characters that overlap. E.g. in the first on the lowercase h wouldn't match either side.

Admittedly the second one looks like it is just "."

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a puzzle you should look closer.

`[^Xa-ehY]|[^f-zW]` is not the same as `.` since they intersect at `h` (`f-z` contains `h`) so it would be the same as `[^h]`

Answer (score 1):

You can throw a bunch of text at them in a regex tester to see if any characters overlap.  It's pretty crude, but your first example [`(\[^Xa-ehY\]|\[^f-zW\])`](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%5B%5EXa-ehY%5D%7C%5B%5Ef-zW%5D%29&input=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%0AABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%0A0123456789%0A) overlaps on the letter 'h'.  The second example does look like it should match anything.